# Recommended way of page navigation in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am new to jQuery mobile. I wanted to know what are the best practice to navigate between pages. Let say I have `page1.html` `page2.html`. Inside `page1.html` i click a link `<a href='page1.html'>load</a>`

so here i want to know that there are two possibilities

1. either just load whole `page2.html`
2. Just load the page2.html inside `<div role="main" class="ui-content">`

In context of jqm which one  is recommended ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a navigation bar in the form of [JQuery Mobile Tabs](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/tabs/) (also created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u1r4mjob/1/))

This will allow you to create a fixed header at the top of your webpage with multiple pages inside one overall page. Its a great technique.

Example HTML from the link provided:

```
<div data-role="tabs" id="tabs">
  <div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#one" data-ajax="false">one</a></li>
      <li><a href="#two" data-ajax="false">two</a></li>
      <li><a href="ajax-content.html" data-ajax="false">three</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="one" class="ui-body-d ui-content">
    <h1>First tab contents</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <li><a href="#">Acura</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Audi</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Cadillac</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ferrari</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can identify the features and allocate them roles using the `data-role` attribute, in this case you assign the `data-role` to a `div` element to act as a tab menu which will then wrap the pages.

To identfy the pages you use a `<a>` element to link to each page, inside the list of tabs. Assigning the ID to a `<div>` to act as a page, you're able to direct those links inside the tabbed menu to show the contents inside the `<div>` presented.

I prefer this options but there are various other options you can take.

**Further Reading**

- Data-role "navbar" [W3C Navbar](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_navbars.asp)
- [JQuery Mobile Navigation](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.3/navigation/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a panel, which you usually see a hamburger menu representing. You tap that and a menu animates (you can choose animation form) out from the left or right (again up to you). ...here is a demo from their documentation  http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/panels/